# default RGB coloring

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, color, generative-art, rasterize

I am playing with some basic genetic algorithms to recreate input images by transparent plane figures (similar like [here:](http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/evolve/)).
Everything would work great but the speed is terrible. I was looking for a problematic part of my code and I found that function I use - `ImageDifference` works very slow for CMYK colors (even if you are comparing CMYK to CMYK), but it is much faster for RGB vs RGB comparison.

The problem is that when I combine figures using `Graphics` like this:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}]}]
```

the result image is in CMYK and hence, to make `ImageDifference` faster, I have to use `ColorConvert` (to RGB) which again is quite slow function.

Is there another way in Mathematica to set that all images created by `Graphics` will be automatically in RGB? Or if you have another ideas how to speed this up, please let me know. :)

**Small demonstration:**

I have some target image. For example:

```
target = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 150]
```

[image]

In every step, I also have some combination of polygons which I want to compare to the target image. So lets say, we have (in some very early stage):

```
k = 5;(*number of points*)
n = 20;(*number of polygons*)

(*opacity, r, g, b, x, y*)
polygons= 
  Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, k], RandomReal[{0, 1}, k]} // Flatten, {n}];

example1 = Graphics[
   Map[
    {
      Opacity[#[[1]]],
      RGBColor[#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]],
      Polygon[{Take[#, {5, 5 + k - 1}], Take[#, {5 + k, 2 k + 4}]} //Transpose]
      }
     &,
    polygons
    ], ImageSize -> {150, 150}
   ]
```

[image]

For demonstration lets also set:

```
example2 = ColorConvert[example1, "RGB"];
```

Now, the difference in applying `ImageData` for those two representations is quite huge:

```
(example1 // ImageData); // AbsoluteTiming (*-> 0.0584582*)
(example2 // ImageData); // AbsoluteTiming (*-> 0.000384866*)
```

Same for the `ImageDifference`:

```
ImageDifference[target,example1]; // AbsoluteTiming (*-> 0.0703736*)
ImageDifference[target,example2]; // AbsoluteTiming (*-> 0.000687233*)
```

Comment: "the result image is in CMYK" ...Um, it isn't? A `Graphics` is not an `Image` and doesn't have an intrinsic colour space, unless you `Rasterize` it or do `Image[graphics, ColorSpace -> space]`.  How are you finding it to be "in CMYK"?

Comment: Can you at least construct a minimum example to demonstrate this behavior you're seeing?

Comment: When you apply ImageData on a result, it will give you matrix of 4-dimensional vectors, which made me think it is in CMYK.

Comment: Ah, you're misreading the output; it's still RGB, plus the alpha channel (which shows up due to your `Opacity[]` directives). Explicitly-set alpha channels slow things down in *Mathematica*, for some reason...

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for explaining. Anyway, I still see some huge performance difference after applying  ColorConvert. I updated my question and added small demonstration.

Answer (score 4):

In your present example the operation that is slow is the rasterization of the `Graphics` expression.  This is implicitly performed by both `ImageDifference[target,example1]` and `ColorConvert[example1, "RGB"]`.  By pre-rasterizing for `example2` you remove this costly step and the `ImageDifference` is two orders of magnitude faster.  If you include the rasterization in the timing it is much closer, though interestingly still a bit faster.

```
ColorConvert[example1, "RGB"] // Head // RepeatedTiming

ImageDifference[target, example1]; // RepeatedTiming

ImageDifference[target, ColorConvert[example1, "RGB"]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.025, Image}    (* note that the Head is Image *)
>
> {0.030, Null}
>
> {0.025, Null}
> ```

This question then becomes: how can one rasterize faster?  Unfortunately I do not have a good answer to that.  You can [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) directly to an Integer array, if that is your target, somewhat faster than using [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html):

```
ColorConvert[example1, "RGB"] // ImageData; // RepeatedTiming

Rasterize[example1, "Data"]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.025, Null}
>
> {0.0213, Null}
> ```

I am afraid however that this is *not* helpful in your situation as the integer array cannot be (directly) used as input for [`ImageDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDifference.html).